# MySQL ODBC 3.51 - How to disable connection pooling from the ODBC GUI?

Tags: odbc, connection-pooling

How do I disable connection pooling for MySQl ODBC Driver 3.51 on Windows7/Server2008 via the ODBC GUI?

I do my own connection pooling at the app level, making connections as and when needed,
and storing them for a fixed period until terminating them if not used.

I use the ODBC's DSN string, so I need to be able to set the "Pooling=False" option
from the ODBC configuration screen.

Answer (score 3):

Found it...

The 32Bit ODBC GUI is started from C:\Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe.  In this GUI, there is a tab on the first screen called "Connection Pooling".  Click on this, you get a list of drivers.  There is a second column to the right that shows the "Pool Timeout".  Double click on the driver name of choice to change it's pooling settings.

The 64Bit ODBC GUI is C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe, works the same way, but you will probably have far fewer drivers loaded and therefore the names will be shorter, and the "Pool Timeout" column will be visible without having to scroll right.

Note, the MySQL drivers were, by default, set to be not pooled.  Hope that helps anyone else who is using a "DSN=MySQL_DSN" type reference and has to use the GUI to configure driver settings.