# Is there a setting or some issue that would cause MySql to wait 1 second between queries?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc

I have a client who needed an old vb.net web app moved from an old server to a new server. When I got the app running on the new server, we noticed it was running very slowly, even though the server is newer and has much better hardware.

I ran a performance analysis on the application, and it was the OdbcDataAdapter.Fill() command that was the major hotspot.

I then enabled the general log in MySQL and tailed it. What I found was that the app was making a heck of a lot of queries (this programmer would execute multiple queries for each result in a search, for example), but they appear to be throttled somewhere.

Here's just a glimpse of the log for a single page request:

```
130223 11:21:48   624 Connect   root@localhost on mydb
          624 Query SET NAMES utf8
          624 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
          624 Query SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
          624 Query set @@sql_select_limit=DEFAULT
          624 Query select count(*) from bg_doc_status where uploaded = 1 and candidateid='51233'
          624 Quit  
130223 11:21:49   625 Connect   root@localhost on mydb
          625 Query SET NAMES utf8
          625 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
          625 Query SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
          625 Query set @@sql_select_limit=DEFAULT
          625 Query select * from bg_doc_status where willfax=1 and candidateid='51233'
          625 Quit  
130223 11:21:50   626 Connect   root@localhost on mydb
          626 Query SET NAMES utf8
          626 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
          626 Query SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
          626 Query set @@sql_select_limit=DEFAULT
          626 Query Select distinct serviceid from bg_service_results where CandidateID='51233'
          626 Quit  
130223 11:21:51   627 Connect   root@localhost on mydb
          627 Query SET NAMES utf8
          627 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
          627 Query SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
          627 Query set @@sql_select_limit=DEFAULT
          627 Query Select count(*) from bg_candidates_selected_services where CandidateID='51233'
          627 Quit
```

We don't need to talk about how bad this programming is :). This guy could be doing a lot of stuff in a single query. But STILL, MySql appears to execute at most one query per second!

If I run any of these queries in the workbench SQL editor, they each take "0.000 sec". If I hit CTRL+ENTER as quickly as I can, the log will show them execute several times per second.

Does anyone know what could be causing this 1 query per second limit? It happens in both development and production.

I have tried both the MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver and the MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver, in both 32 and 64 bit.

**I found the solution: The odbc.open() is what was taking the full second. Apparently it was the dns lookup (for localhost!) that was taking the time. Changing the db server address in my web.config to 127.0.0.1 fixed it. It looks like [this person](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,278517,278517) found the same problem.**

Comment: Why not use the [MySQL .Net connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)?

Comment: This is an old app and I would rather not go into the source. Since the same code runs very quickly on the old server, I'd really like to take a shot at configuration before rewriting data code in this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: The odbc.open() is what was taking the full second. Apparently it was the dns lookup (for localhost!) that was taking the time. Changing the db server address in my web.config to 127.0.0.1 fixed it. It looks like [this person](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,278517,278517) found the same problem.

Comment: Is connection pooling enabled?  Otherwise, it should only do a DNS lookup for the first query.  After the connection is established, it shouldn't have to do another DNS lookup for each subsequent query.  Enabling it should be as easy as changing the connection string, which it seems isn't hard coded based on your solution.

Comment: Also, if you want to use "Localhost", you should just add it to your "hosts" file.  Older versions of windows required it to be there. Newer versions of windows no longer require it, as it's hardcoded into the network drivers to alwasy go to the local machine.  The computer should always look in your hosts file first before doing a DNS query, so lookups should be relatively quick.

Comment: This is how it looks: `<add key="StrConn" value="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=mydb;UID=myusr;PWD=mypqd;OPTION=3;"/>`

Comment: Actually, for ODBC it seems like it's configured at the ODBC driver level. Take a look at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502660/mysql-odbc-3-51-how-to-disable-connection-pooling-from-the-odbc-gui)

Comment: The server is Windows Server 2012, so I guess it shouldn't need to be there?

Comment: I think it doesn't need to be there in 2012.  In Windows 8, it's there, but commented out, with a message explaining why.

Comment: I added `Pooling=True;` to the connection string based on [these examples](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql). I didn't notice a difference, but I will ask the customers who use this app daily if it feels snappier.

Comment: You can try leaving the pooling on, and set the connection string back to localhost to see if the original problem doesn't come back. Although I'd probably leave it at 127.0.0.1 just to avoid future problems.